# Applescript to quit all active browser processes

Tags: applescript

I am trying to quit all the active browsers using the below code, but am unable to get the list of all active browsers to quit.

```
tell application "System Events"

    set appList to every process whose visible is true

    repeat with thisApp in appList
        tell process browser
            quit
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set ProcessList to name of every process
    if "Safari" is in ProcessList then
        tell application "Safari"
            quit
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

Repeat as needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what browsers you have installed (and why wouldn't you?), there's no need to bother getting the processes, you can just loop through a list of browsers and send a quit message:

```
set browserList to {"Safari", "Google Chrome", "Firefox"}

repeat with browser in browserList
    tell application browser to quit
end repeat
```

Just make sure to edit `browserList` to include only the browsers you have installed, otherwise you'll get an AppleScript prompt asking you to locate the ones you don't.